# Translating EPSG:4326 lon lat coordinates to xy using pyproj

Tags: python, coordinate-system, pyproj

I'm trying to work out the details of using pyproj to translate the lat lon coordinates from the [USGS Earthquake feed](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/csv.php) to xy coordinates corresponding to those positions on a basemap of a determined width and height and origin at the upper left. My code so far naively uses PIL/pillow to translate lon lat to xy positions and draw circles without taking into account the EPSG:4326 projection of the basemap:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

# open basemap image file
basemap = Image.open(basemap_path).convert('RGBA)

# resize to desired map size
basemap.thumbnail(width, height, Image.LANCZOS)

# get proportional height
width_bmp, height_bmp = basemap.size

# create background frame and paste basemap on it
img=Image.new('RGB',(width, height), color = '#000000')
img.paste(basemap, (0,0), basemap)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img, 'RGBA')

width_scale = width/360
height_scale = height_bmp/180

# usgs data has been parsed into a list
for quake in earthquake_list:
    lon = float(quake["longitude"])
    lat = float(quake["latitude"])
    mag = float(quake["mag"])

    # want to use pyproj to translate coordinates here instead of the following
    cx = (lon + 180) * width_scale
    cy = (90-lat) * height_scale
    r  = scaleRadius(mag)

    # draw earthquake circles
    draw.ellipse((cx-r, cy-r, cx+r, cy+r), fill = colormap(mag))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img.save(filepath, quality=100)
```

I've gone through the [documentation](https://proj.org/index.html) and have a general sense that I would use something like:

```
cx, cy = pyproj.transform("EPSG:4326", "xy", lon, lat)
```

with some width and height dimensions. Running the line above gives the error:

```
TypeError: p1 must be a Proj class
```

**Update** I do get values for:

```
p = Proj(proj = 'longlat', ellps='WGS84')
cx,cy = p(lon, lat)
```

In this case a (lon, lat) input of `(-110, 39)` gives the output `1.923, 0.688` which isn't right. What I need is a projection function that takes the lon, lat and the width and height of the image and outputs the x, y coordinates. I would write this on my own, but I can't find a suitable equation for that conversion and was hoping to find this capability in proj.

**UPDATE** Here is the basemap I am using.

[image]

And here is the resulting drawing. I'm assuming the centerpoints for the circles marking earthquakes are off, because I am using Cartesian coordinates for lon, lat, but the basemap was created with a projection and thus must have a distortion from x, y Cartesian coordinates.

[image]

Also, I realize I need to put my legend on a logarithmic scale. Haven't gotten to that yet.

Comment: Note, EPSG:4326 coordinates are in lat/long order

Comment: I'm not sure how you can have a `(not-georeferenced) global EPSG:4326 basemap`.  Either the base map is in EPSG:4326 and therefore georeferenced, or it's just a map image with no CRS.  Can you edit the question to expand on what you mean  by the statement.

Comment: I've rephrased that description. Thanks.

Comment: X/Y in relation to *what*?

Comment: x, y in relation to an image of width, height with origin at the upper left. This is in the code but I'll spell it out in the description.

Comment: This does not add upp. EPSG:4326 is not a projection, it is a geodetic datum, but it could be taken to mean "just plot longitude along the X axis and latitude along the Y axis", in which case there is no need to drag pyproj into the equation. Are you *sure* your basemap is just unprojected lat/lon? Could you put a link to the map image somewhere so we can have a look at it? And regardless of which projection it is, a circle on the surface of the planet almost certainly won't project to a circle on the map.

Comment: I have updated the post with images of the basemap as well as the result of drawing the circles at the lon, lat coordinates from the USGS data.

Comment: It does indeed seem like your basemap is in the (somewhat brutal) "projection" of letting x=longitude and y=latitude. To me, who knows little about earthquakes, the positions of your circles look plausible (you get them in California, Iceland and S. E. Asia, but not in Sweden :-) ). What is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: The basemap was constructed using EPSG:4326, so I am assuming that there is a distortion, which would be most apparent moving from the equator toward the poles, that does not correspond to an x, y Cartesian placement of lon, lat coordinates. If this doesn't make sense, I can rephrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I overlay your basemap on an Equirectangular projection, it fits perfectly. So this means your basemap really just uses the simple "projection" of plotting longitudes as x and latitudes as y. Which means the only thing you have to worry about is to check the size of the image, which you already do in your formulas.

```
cx = (lon + 180) * width_scale
cy = (90-lat) * height_scale
```

These will work properly for your needs, to the nearest pixel. In fact, I verified the Earthquakes on USGS on that date, and your points are all in the right location!